# Error in findViewById in Android

Tags: android, findviewbyid

I am getting error in `speed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.speed);` saying **"speed cannot be resolved or it is not a field"**.

My layout is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".SpeedometerActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/download"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="300dp"
        android:text="Begin Test" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/speed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/meter"
        android:layout_marginLeft="191dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/meter"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView speed;
    Button download;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.speedometer);

        download = (Button)findViewById(R.id.download);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        h = new Handler();
        new speedTask().execute();
        speed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.speed);
    }
}
```

Please anybody help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Add type to your speed button `(Button) speed = (Button) findViewById(R.id.speed);` By the way, you can't cast Textview to button.

Comment: speed is textview how you change to button

Comment: Please paste your full MainActivity.Java file.

Comment: @ChiragRaval  I have pasted my full code, i have made certain changes please see it, still error is there

Answer (score 4):

```
"speed cannot be resolved or it is not a field"
```

Check if any errors in your resource files. Follow the suggestion by blackbelt. If you have errors in resource files your R.java will not be generated. Fix it. also check if you have `import android.R;` if so remove it.

Further you have

```
<TextView

    android:id="@+id/speed"
```

Its a textview

Casting it to button

```
 speed = (Button)findViewById(R.id.speed);
```

Should be

```
 TextView speed =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.speed);
```

Comment: @Raghunandan I disagree. the OP is complaining about a compile time error. You are talking about a Runtime error

Comment: ya i have already initialized speed to TextView but still i am getting same error

Comment: import java.util.List;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
impotr android.os.Bundle;                                            import android.view.View;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.app.Activity;                                  import android.widget.TextView;these are my imports @Raghunandan

Comment: @user3153083 import R from your package. and also check if you have any errors in any of the resources files.

Comment: I have added "import android.R;" but still showing same error @Raghunandan

Comment: @user3153083 you should not remove that import. Re-check all your resource files. check if you have errors in any resource files. fix it.

Comment: @user3153083 check if you have R.java under the gen folder. Your R.java will not be generated if you have any errors in your resource files.

Comment: @Raghunandan i have edited my code and pasted it please check it, but still error is there

Answer (score 2):

You should check if the `R` class you imported is the one of your project and not the android's one. Also you are casting to the wrong object, as correctly stated from @Raghunandan

Comment: +1 for answering to the real problem the OP is facing.

Comment: +1 from me also you answered it right before me. i looked at the code but missed the first statement and until @ZouZou pointed me i din't re-read the post.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are type cast TextView to Button. So please change your code as below.

```
TextView speed = (Button)findViewById(R.id.speed);
```

**Note : Here you are not able to import your project R file, first please check your xml file and try to resolve xml error first.**

**Please remove `import android.R;` from your activity if you have import it.**

Go to your MainActivity.Java file and Press **CTRL+SHIFT+O**. It will automatically import all necessary packages.

Comment: I have impoterd as u said and also there is no error in XML but showing same error

Answer (score 0):

It has created a duplicate so give as follows

```
Button speed1;
speed1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.speed);
```

It will work!